# Make the first character following a semicolon uppercase, for each line of a text file

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file like this

```
John Doe;john Doe is ...;he lives in ...
Mike Nelson;mike Nelson works for ...;he makes ...
Marcy William;marcy's mother is ...;marcy travels a lot...
```

I want to convert every character following a semicolon to uppercase, so the final result is

```
John Doe;John Doe is ...;He lives in ...
Mike Nelson;Mike Nelson works for ...;He makes ...
Marcy William;Marcy's mother is ...;Marcy travels a lot...
```

keeping the rest intact.

This file contains accented letters and is coded in UTF-8.

Comment: `perl -pe 's/;(.)/;\u$1/g'`.

Comment: almost there. This is not working with accented letters.

Comment: It does, if you're telling perl to use utf-8: `echo ';ük;ук' | perl -CiIO -pe 's/;(.)/;\u$1/g'` => `;Ük;Ук`

Comment: brilliant. This second command is working perfectly. Please make this an answer.

Answer (score 10):

GNU Sed:

```
sed 's/;[[:lower:]]/\U&/g' file
```

For every lowercase character following a semicolon (`;[[:lower:]]`), we make it uppercase with the [`\U` special sequence](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html). The `g` flag substitutes all occurrences in a line.

If GNU Sed is not available, a POSIX compliant alternative is to use [Ex](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).

```
printf '%s\n' '%s/;[[:lower:]]/\U&/g' '%p' | ex file
```

The substitute command is the same, but all lines should be addressed with `%`.
`%p` prints the output. If you wish to directly modify the file, replace `%p` by `x`.

Answer (score 8):

Not awk or sed, but perl:

```
perl -C -pe 's/;(.)/;\u$1/g'
```

The `-C` option turns UTF-8 i/o depending on or off depending on your locale environment variables (`LC_ALL`, etc); if you want it to assume UTF-8 input and output unconditionally, change it to `-CSD`.

Notice that Unicode capitalization is tricky. That will turn **ihsan** into **Ihsan** instead of the correct **İhsan** (the turkish name has a dot above i even when uppercase).

Comment: Yes, are you sure `i̇` is in utf8? `uniprops i̇` gives me `no character named ‹◌i̇›`. On the other hand, `perl` with `-C` correctly handled Greek `ά` to `Ά` or `ώ` to `Ώ`.

Comment: "İhsan" starts with [U+0130](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I), which is, of course, a Unicode character. It's lowercase equivalent is `i`, not `i` + combining dot above.

Comment: Ah, I see. So the only way to do this right, presumably, would be to specify the language as Turkish since there's no way of knowing that `i` should become `İ` otherwise. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way, using perl:

```
perl -C -pe 's/;(.)/";" . uc($1)/eg' file
```

Since you don't show any accents in your input file, I used this for testing:

```
$ cat file
John Doe;john Doe is ...;he lives in ...
Mike Nelson;mike Nelson works for ...;he makes ...
Émilie du Châtelet;émilie du Châtelet;works for ...;she makes ...
Marcy William;marcy's mother is ...;marcy travels a lot...
Άσπα Κυριάκου;άσπα's brother is ...; άσπα likes fish
```

Which produces:

```
$ perl -C -pe 's/;(.)/";" . uc($1)/eg' file
John Doe;John Doe is ...;He lives in ...
Mike Nelson;Mike Nelson works for ...;He makes ...
Émilie du Châtelet;Émilie du Châtelet;Works for ...;She makes ...
Marcy William;Marcy's mother is ...;Marcy travels a lot...
Άσπα Κυριάκου;Άσπα's brother is ...; άσπα likes fish
```

#### Explanation

- `-C`: (see `man perlrun` for details) essentialy, this enables utf8.
- `-pe`: read the input file line by line and print every line after applying the script given by `e`.

The work happens in the substitution operator, whose general format is `s/old/new/flags`. This means it will subsitute `old` with `new` and `flags` control how it will work. Here, the flags used are `e` which enables perl code in the substitution and `g` which means "apply to all matches of the line".

The `;(.)` captures every character found after a `;` and saves it as `$1`. We then replace this with a `;`, and the character converted to upper case (`uc($1)`).

Answer (score 2):

Using @terdon's sample file and GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed -e 's/;\(.\)/;\U\1/g' file
John Doe;John Doe is ...;He lives in ...
Mike Nelson;Mike Nelson works for ...;He makes ...
Émilie du Châtelet;Émilie du Châtelet;Works for ...;She makes ...
Marcy William;Marcy's mother is ...;Marcy travels a lot...
Άσπα Κυριάκου;Άσπα's brother is ...; άσπα likes fish
$
```

Answer (score 2):

**using Raku (formerly known as Perl6)**

An advantage of the Perl6/Raku project is that it's designed to handle Unicode gracefully, from the ground up. Thanks to @terdon for posting a nice test file:

```
~$ raku -pe 's:g/ \;(.) /;{$0.uc}/;'  terdon_uni.txt
John Doe;John Doe is ...;He lives in ...
Mike Nelson;Mike Nelson works for ...;He makes ...
Émilie du Châtelet;Émilie du Châtelet;Works for ...;She makes ...
Marcy William;Marcy's mother is ...;Marcy travels a lot...
Άσπα Κυριάκου;Άσπα's brother is ...; άσπα likes fish
```

Above we see the capture of the first character after a semicolon. The `:g` flag (short for `:global`) moves to the head of the `s///` operator, so we know from the get-go what sort of match we're after.  Note captures in Raku start `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, etc. The 'matching' (left) half of the `s///` operator is whitespace-tolerant, which improves readability. The 'replacement' (right) half of the `s///` operator uses `{…}` to indicate a closure.

Below I use Raku's `<(…)>` capturing marker. Raku's `<(…)>` circumfix is equivalent to Perl5's `\K` flag. A match is performed but the `<(…)>` marker tells Raku to drop everything outside `<(…)>` and load the inside (capture) into `$/`. Because Raku performs the entire match but only captures the exact character(s) you want to change, writing the replacement is greatly simplified:

```
~$ raku -pe 's:g/ \; <(.)> /{$/.uc}/;'  terdon_uni.txt
John Doe;John Doe is ...;He lives in ...
Mike Nelson;Mike Nelson works for ...;He makes ...
Émilie du Châtelet;Émilie du Châtelet;Works for ...;She makes ...
Marcy William;Marcy's mother is ...;Marcy travels a lot...
Άσπα Κυριάκου;Άσπα's brother is ...; άσπα likes fish
```

HTH.

https://raku.org

Answer (score 1):

command

```
awk -F ";" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)}}' filename|sed -e "N;s/\n/;/g" -e "N;s/\n/;/g"
```

output

```
John Doe;John Doe is ...;He lives in ...
Mike Nelson;Mike Nelson works for ...;He makes ...
Marcy William;Marcy's mother is ...;Marcy travels a lot...
```